# Javascript URL inside an iframe does not execute in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, forms

I have written this code for Firefox:

```
<html><head><title>No</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="javascript:void(alert('Yes'));">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>$($('form').submit())</script></body></html>
```

It correctly displays the alert box.
However, when i run this inside an iframe, with this code:

```
<html><body><iframe src="click.php"></iframe></body></html>
```

i don't get the alert box, not even if i click the submit button myself.
What is going on exactly? The same code works in Chromium

Comment: Just tried it without the two `<script>` tags, and it works fine. So maybe it's something weird happening with jquery? Firefox 3.6.10

Comment: actually it worked for me too on FF 3.6.10

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing `$($('form').submit())` - (wrapping the jQuery object that is returned in another jQuery object)?

Comment: I don't understand why you have javascript in the action field. If you want to process the form in javascript, use onsubmit event.

Comment: now that you point it out, i think i was trying to use the idiom $(function), which is the same as $.ready(function). but that's not callable, so i guess i have a bug there too...

Comment: Thought perhaps that was what you were after. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't do that then!

It doesn't make any sense to submit a form to a `javascript:` URL. Use a `submit` event handler to pick up the form submission and execute script, eg using jQuery:

```
$('#someform').submit(function() {
    alert('Yes');
    return false;
});
```

A good rule of thumb about when to use `javascript:` URLs is: never.

Comment: i should have warned that the code didn't necessarily have to make sense :-) this is part of a mozilla mochitest, and i need a way to "click" (or at least, to make firefox follow the paths i want to test) javascript urls automatically

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a problem with FF4 so I'll discuss it on their bugzilla if it's really their fault. I have modified the source so I'm not even sure it is a bug...